# WKWebView change frame and make content fit without reload

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to embed a social post (instagram, Facebook and twitter) into `WKWebView`, so I'used `WKUserScript` to calculate height.

Unfortunately once the `WKWebView didFinish` loading, changing the frame have no effect on shown content as you can see in picture.

Here's my code :

```
var height: CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet {

        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,
                                    width: SocialWebViewHelper.webViewWidth,
                                    height: self.height)
        self.webView.frame = frame
        self.webView.sizeToFit()
        self.webView.sizeThatFits(frame.size)
        self.webView.scrollView.sizeToFit()
        self.webView.scrollView.sizeThatFits(frame.size)
    }
}

func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {

    guard let responseDict = message.body as? [String: Any],
        let height = responseDict["height"] as? CGFloat else {
            return
    }
    let newHeight = max(self.height, CGFloat(height))
    if self.height != newHeight {
        self.height = newHeight
    }
}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

[image: in picture]:

Comment: Can you clarify ?  How do you set responseDict["height"]? I mean the javascript part.

Comment: Is it the webView or the View containing the web view that is staying unchanged? Or are you referring to the top and bottom blank around the image, in which case I'd suggest to add css style to remove padding, margin to the body, or make the body transparent.

Comment: @Arc Since it's the content of the WebView, it's fully and successfully loaded but it's not shown. The problem was in `HTML.body.height` is was not changing when I set the webView height, or even after web view finish loading.
So I' had to use a Javascript to update the body.height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that despite changing the WebView height the `HTML.Body.Frame.Height` was not changing.

So I'used a JavaScript to update the frame height when updating the WebViews height, like this :

```
 private var height: CGFloat = SocialCellHelper.webViewDefaultHeight {
    didSet {
        self.webView.frame.size.height = 1
        self.webView.frame.size.height = self.height
        // Update iframe height manually
        // Fix problem of WebView content height not fitting WebViews frame height
        self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].style.height = \(self.height);") { (_, _) in
            self.webViewHeight.accept(self.height)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following approach of getting web content height worked for me

```swift
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.height = height as! CGFloat
        }
    })
}
```